# Is there a way to see the type of tags/features pulled in an OSMnx multigraph?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, osmnx

I'm new to OSMnx / Overpass queries. 
I'm trying to pull data on rail networks in global cities. I'm using the script in Python below to pull rail data in London, for example.

There are a number of sub-categories within railway infrastructure (eg,  rail, light rail, tram, etc). I wondered if there is any way to see the kind of tags/sub categories used within the data I have pulled.

```
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_point((y,x), 
                        distance = 20000,
                        distance_type = 'bbox', 
                        infrastructure = 'way["railway"~"rail"]',
                        network_type = 'none',
                        )

ox.plot_graph(G)
```

I know I could also individually go through each subcategory using `'way["railway"~"subway"]'` for example, but I wondered if there was way of somehow query the actual multigraph to figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can peruse what railway tag/values you got by adding "railway" as a tag to retain in the graph, using the [ox.config](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.utils.config) function:

```py
import osmnx as ox
utw = ox.settings.useful_tags_way + ['railway']
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True, useful_tags_way=utw)
G = ox.graph_from_address('London, UK', dist=5000, custom_filter='["railway"]')
ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False)['railway'].value_counts()
```

Also note that the old `infrastructure` param was deprecated and replaced by the `custom_filter` param in a previous release.